# Как найти позицию пользователя и совместить запросы в один общий MSSQL запрос?

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос, union

У нас есть БД MSSQL. UserID, FName, LName, NStore, RegionStore, PickRate, WaitTime - это наши columns. 
Нужно найти пользователя с UserID, найти позицию в отсортированой БД относительно PickRate, WaitTime. После получить TOP 5 пользователй по PickRate и WaitTime. Соединить в один запрос.

Мои запросы:

````
SELECT MainUser.PositionPK, MainUser.PositionWT, MainUser.UserID, MainUser.FirstName + ' ' + MainUser.LastName AS FullName, MainUser.StoreNumber, MainUser.StoreRegion, MainUser.PickRate, MainUser.WaitTime FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS PositionPK, null AS PositionWT, T1.UserID, T1.FirstName, T1.LastName, T1.StoreNumber, T1.StoreRegion, T1.PickRate, null AS WaitTime
FROM user T1, user T2 WHERE T1.UserID = 'fd50lom' AND T2.PickRate >= T1.PickRate
GROUP BY T1.UserID, T1.FirstName, T1.LastName, T1.StoreNumber, T1.StoreRegion, T1.PickRate 
UNION ALL
SELECT null AS PositionPK, COUNT(*) AS PositionWT, T1.UserID, T1.FirstName, T1.LastName, T1.StoreNumber, T1.StoreRegion, null AS PickRate, T1.WaitTime
FROM user T1, user T2 WHERE T1.UserID = 'fd50lom' AND T2.WaitTime <= T1.WaitTime
GROUP BY T1.UserID, T1.FirstName, T1.LastName, T1.StoreNumber, T1.StoreRegion, T1.WaitTime) MainUser```

В выше указаном мы получаем:
    null   6 fd50lom    Sam Nora    2   1234    2       null
    1   null fd50lom    Sam Nora    2   1234    null    00:01

Здесь хотелось бы получить одну строчку:
     1   6   fd50lom    Sam Nora    2   1234    2       00:01

И соединить вместе с следующим запросом:

SELECT TOP (5) RANK () OVER (ORDER BY PickRate DESC) PositionPK, null AS PositionWT, UserID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, PickRate, null AS WaitTime
FROM user
WHERE StoreNumber = 2 AND Date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST (SYSUTCDATETIME() AS Date))
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (5) null AS PositionPK, RANK () OVER (ORDER BY WaitTime ASC) Position, UserID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, null AS PickRate, WaitTime
FROM user
WHERE StoreNumber = 2 AND Date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST (SYSUTCDATETIME() AS Date))

А если кто то оптимизирует и засунет в один запрос... вообще бомба

Спасибо за внимание.
````

Answer (score 0):

Первую часть сделал:

```
SELECT
  TablePK.PositionPK,
  TableWT.PositionWT,
  TablePK.FirstName + ' ' + TablePK.LastName AS FullName,
  TablePK.StoreNumber,
  TablePK.StoreRegion,
  TablePK.Date,
  TablePK.PickRate,
  TableWT.WaitTime
FROM (SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS PositionPK,
  NULL AS PositionWT,
  T1.UserID,
  T1.FirstName,
  T1.LastName,
  T1.StoreNumber,
  T1.StoreRegion,
  T1.Date,
  T1.PickRate,
  NULL AS WaitTime
FROM Game.dbo.[user] T1,
     Game.dbo.[user] T2
WHERE T1.UserID = 'fd50lom'
AND T2.PickRate >= T1.PickRate
GROUP BY T1.UserID,
         T1.FirstName,
         T1.LastName,
         T1.StoreNumber,
         T1.StoreRegion,
         T1.Date,
         T1.PickRate) TablePK
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  NULL AS PositionPK,
  COUNT(*) AS PositionWT,
  T1.UserID,
  T1.FirstName,
  T1.LastName,
  T1.StoreNumber,
  T1.StoreRegion,
  T1.Date,
  NULL AS PickRate,
  T1.WaitTime
FROM Game.dbo.[user] T1,
     Game.dbo.[user] T2
WHERE T1.UserID = 'fd50lom'
AND T2.WaitTime <= T1.WaitTime
GROUP BY T1.UserID,
         T1.FirstName,
         T1.LastName,
         T1.StoreNumber,
         T1.StoreRegion,
         T1.Date,
         T1.WaitTime) TableWT
  ON TablePK.UserID = TableWT.UserID
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `CTE` и оконной функции `ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`

Comment: Спасибо. Тоже об этом подумал...